# IE9 loses requests to a local Catalyst server

Tags: perl, internet-explorer, networking, internet-explorer-9, catalyst

Okay, this is a hard one. I have a Catalyst server I can access just fine from Firefox 4, Chromium 12, and IE 8 and 9 on other computers.  When I try to access it from IE9 on my own machine (the same machine the server is on), I get strange timeouts and delays. The Catalyst server's output doesn't show these delays and the IE9 traffic view doesn't even show that the request was ever sent!

[image: IE9 Request timeline]

While the server is hanging up it's using 100% of a processor core but then it drops back to idle without outputting anything.  This same request takes 5ms when requested from Chrome or FF.

If I ^C the server while it's locked up I get this frighteningly low-level error:

```
Can't coerce UNKNOWN to string in sysread 
   at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/Catalyst/Engine/HTTP.pm line 440.
Can't call method "_socket_data" without a package or object reference 
   at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/Catalyst/Engine/HTTP.pm line 358.
panic: pad_free curpad 
   at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/Catalyst/Engine/HTTP.pm line 358.
```

What's different about how IE9 routes requests to local sockets?

Environment info:

- Windows 7 Pro x64
- Strawberry Perl 5.10.1 x86
- Catalyst 5.80032
- Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does the problem go away if you run [Fiddler](http://getfiddler.com)?

If so, the problem you're likely hitting is that your webserver isn't properly multithreaded and IE9's background connection feature is causing your server to hang as it deadlocks due to a background connection which doesn't have a request on it.

Comment: Using Fiddler works nicely! Can you elaborate or link to more info on the background connection feature? How does Fiddler change IE's background connection so it isn't a problem anymore? My catalyst server is definitely not multi-threaded but it wasn't a problem before IE9. I'm curious as to why it only happens with local connections. Remote IE9 connections don't seem to have the same problem.